# Sort Mongoose data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, database

I'm working on sorting my mongoose data.  Currently what I am doing below is working perfectly:

```
 Rentals.find({}).sort({featured: -1})
```

I am now trying to add a way to not show the rentals that are "reserved."

I've been trying this but it is not working:

```
if (!Rentals.reserved) { 
Rentals.find({}).sort({featured: -1})
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `reserved` is a Boolean, then just do

```
Rentals.find({ reserved: false }).sort({featured: -1})
```

Comment: You rock @Mikey